# Webdrivermanager is unable to access Selenium web driver due to company proxy

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, proxy, webdriver

I am using the latest version of bonigarcia/webdrivermanager. In my company they are not allowing to access the driver api website for downloading driver exe or api while using company VPN or the company proxy (agent is behind a proxy on Azure DevOps Pipeline)

For instance, it cannot access the below links from the release hosted agent server:

- MS Edge WebDriver: http://msedgedriver.azureedge.net:443
- Chrome WebDriver: chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443

Code:

```
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);
```

The above line of code throws the below errors as seen on the pipeline:

```
> 2022-07-28T13:00:34.7272320Z Starting test execution, please wait...
> 2022-07-28T13:00:34.7980370Z A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
> 2022-07-28T13:00:42.8980608Z   Failed VerifyTextPresent [4 s]
> 2022-07-28T13:00:42.8980950Z   Error Message:
> 2022-07-28T13:00:42.8981422Z    OneTimeSetUp: System.Net.WebException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [::ffff:XX.XX.XXX.XX]:443 (msedgedriver.azureedge.net:443)
> 2022-07-28T13:00:42.8982137Z   ----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [::ffff:XX.XX.XXX.XX]:443 (msedgedriver.azureedge.net:443)
> 2022-07-28T13:00:42.8982887Z   ----> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [::ffff:XX.XX.XXX.XX]:443...
```

I tried fiddling with the proxy as below but it did not work:

```
new DriverManager().WithProxy(proxy uri from hosted agent server)
                   .SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);
```

and also:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();   
options.AddArgument("--proxy-server=http://" + "Proxy IP or URL" + ":" + "Proxy Port");
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Notes:

- Framework is required to run while VPN is on or on the azure devops
  pipeline which is behind a proxy
- Technology used: Selenium C#

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message, stack trace, and identify the line of code that throws this exception. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Firewall rules maybe? Try adding a "Powershell" task to the pipeline that calls `Invoke-WebRequest 'http://msedgedriver.azureedge.net:443/'` -- what error do you get? If using the proxy correctly doesn't resolve the issue, it starts to feel like a firewall problem.

Comment: @GregBurghardt All right, I'll try it out and see how it goes. Thank you.